# Visual Studio 2015 - 2017 pack multiaple .exe files in one and install them

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, visual-studio-2017

I have multi .exe files that I want to pack them into one .exe application and then install them when I run the new application.

- Is it possible/doable?
- Is there anyone who have done it?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The solution is a Setup Wizard installer project, in Visual Studio -> Add files in Application folder -> right click project -> View -> Custom Actions -> Install -> Add your applications files to be installed.